# Is text in SVG selectable/copyable in browsers?

Tags: browser-support

More and more browsers support SVG. Is the text in SVG selectable / **copy**'able?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.pandimaniacs.com/whatissvg.php)

> That's right, you can select and copy text right out of an SVG! The SVG does not store the text and letters as shapes, but by their "meaning". Given a good SVG viewer or SVG-capable browser, you can select and copy text as you would in a normal document. Note that this will not work with all SVGs: Since the exact font (the "looks") of a text is often important, and not everyonehas every font installed, some SVG artists convert the letters into shapes. This keeps their appearance, but loses the "meaning", so a viewer no longer knows what letters the shapes represent.

[From the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html)

> In many viewing scenarios, the user will be able to search for and select text strings and copy selected text strings to the system clipboard

Comment: Just to clarify: the spec says it should be supported, but at the moment only opera and webkit support selectable svg text. Firefox has had this [long-standing bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292498) since 2005

Comment: The bug I mentioned is now fixed in firefox nightly builds since yesterday.